# How to count the number of times a year has been repeated from DATE type in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am working with a slightly complex query where I have to count the number of times an year has come in the `publication_date` column. I am using the Query builder from laravel and doing something like:

```
$publication_years = Patent::whereIn('id', $ids)->select(DB::raw('publication_date, COUNT(YEAR(publication_date)) AS count'))->groupBy('publication_date')->get();
```

But this is not working. This is still using the whole date to check. How can I correct this? I have tried `SUBSTR` too and I also tried to convert it using `CONVERT` and `CAST` but in vain? Anyone has any idea?

Comment: You should GROUP BY the same value. (Of course then you can’t select column publication_date any more in the same statement.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with laravel but this query might be helpful for you

```
SELECT YEAR(publication_date) AS date_year, COUNT(YEAR(publication_date)) AS date_year_count FROM `your_table` 
GROUP BY date_year
```

Answer (score 1):

You should group by with `YEAR('publication_date')` instead of full date. So your query might look something like this,

```
$publication_years = Patent::whereIn('id', $ids)->select(DB::raw('YEAR(publication_date), COUNT(YEAR(publication_date)) AS count'))->groupBy(DB::raw('YEAR(publication_date)'))->get();
```

---

Because the following

```
groupBy('publication_date')
```

will group by the result-set by **publication_date** instead of year of publication_date.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is just fetch the date field from the table 'publication_date' using a select query and  check the numbers of rows to get the year count.